# Ubuntu 18.04 never been able to apt-get update; 403 Forbidden ... repository is not signed

Tags: apt, updates, 18.04

First off, I am not a programmer, so please write replies that are intelligible by a layperson. I have spent days trying to solve this problem and am still stuck, so I am finally asking for help.

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on this desktop at work, and everything works fine except that it is unable to update. I open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get update`, and this is the response I receive:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I can open http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu in my browser with no problems. I can go to the address 91.189.88.162 in my browser and it takes me to a page called "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page". I have tried updating from different servers and get this same problem every time. When Ubuntu tries to update itself through the Software & Updates app, it also fails. There is a firewall here at the office, "FortiNet, powered by FortiGuard", which blocks websites that might distract the peons. I asked the IT guy here for help, but we literally don't speak the same language (I am in India).

Please let me know what other information I can give you to help understand the problem.

-D

Answer (score 1):

1. Launch "Software and Updates".
2. Select the "Ubuntu Software" tab.
3. Go down to "Download from".
4. Use the pull-down menu to select "Main Server".
5. Enter your password when prompted.
6. Click "Close".
7. Click "Reload".