# Ubuntu Linux 22.04.3 Update Issues

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04

Getting the following error when trying to carry out any updates. I can ping google via host or dns fine

```
Err:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 192.168.30.10 3128]
Err:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 192.168.30.10 3128]
Err:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 192.168.30.10 3128]
```

Plus I get these errors too

```
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 192.168.30.10 3128]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 never been able to apt-get update; 403 Forbidden ... repository is not signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054413/ubuntu-18-04-never-been-able-to-apt-get-update-403-forbidden-repository-is)